# Automating a dissolve and merge function using a lookup table with a postcode shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, postcode

I'm not any kind of QGIS power user.

I have some CSV data which includes postcodes, local authority names, and a reference label. I have access to the postcode shapefile for the UK.

What I need is a shapefile with one polygon for each of the reference labels, made up of the polygons of each postcode area that it is recorded against in my lookup table. Some postcodes could have two or more reference labels, so might appear multiple times in the table, so I expect to have overlapping polygons in my final output.

As a manual process, I can select all the postcode polygons for a particular reference label, save them as a new shapefile, dissolve them into a single shape, rinse and repeat for every label, and then save all those shapes as a single shapefile layer.

But sadly that is a huge task, way beyond the time or resources I have available.

Any ideas as to how I might achieve this with some clever piece of code?

(Also asking in QGIS subreddit)

Answer (score 1):

So I understood properly, you want to join a table to a postcode layer and then disolve it.

This can be achieved as a `virtual layer`.

Go the the menu `layer / add layer / add-edit virtual layer` and enter the following query. You would have to change the layer name and field name(s) to suit your needs.

You can then export this layer to a Shapefile.

```sql
SELECT tbl.label, ST_UNION(lyr.geometry) as geometry
FROM myCSV tbl
  JOIN postcodelayer lyr ON tbl.postcode = lyr.postcode
GROUP BY tbl.label
```